# Making a conditional regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

I have some troubles making this regexp:

I simply want the regexp test to fail if the input contains this symbol `"<"` directly followed by a letter, i.e something like: `<[^a-zA-Z]`

But I want it to work even if the `"<"` is not found. How can I do that?

**EDIT: some examples**

```
<Wrong example
Wrong <Example

Good Example
< Good Example
Good < Example
Good< Example
Good Example<
```

**EDIT 2:**
When working with asp.net, you can't send a form with this text in an input for example:

```
<Previous
```

**EDIT 3:** This regular expression will be passed in a control that I cannot change, and it works by validating the input with a regular expression. Therefore I cannot match for the bad input

Comment: Bring examples. Some valid and some invalid.

Comment: What do you mean by "work"? And what do you mean by "work even if the `<1` is not found"? The regular expression you supplied will match (succeed) if the source string contains a two character sequence consisting of the less-than symbol (`<`) followed by any single character other than an upper- or lower-case letter A-Z. It will not match (fail) if the source string does not contain that sequence. Exactly what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Let's say I have an html input on a form, and I don't want the user to write the less-than symbol followed by a character, because it will result in an error. The application server will crash as it will think it could be an attempt to compromise the security, like an attack by script

Comment: @GianT971: Just so you know, the "correct answer" to this problem is not to use regex, but rather to HTML-escape anything you might display on a page (either as it is stored in the database or every time it is displayed).

Comment: I wish I could upvote @Platinum Azure's comment more than once.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure you mean by using Javascript I guess? Actually I don't have the possibility to use it for my purpose...This will be used on a "home made" framework (not made by me uh) that does not give me much choice

Comment: @GianT971: Actually, it's better to do this on the server side, because users can get around JavaScript validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A negative lookahead regex on its own like

```
^(?!.*<[a-zA-Z])
```

would check that a letter never followed a left angle bracket, but an empty string would match your criteria. Do you also need to make sure it contains at least one alpha, like this?

```
^(?!.*<[a-zA-Z]).*[a-zA-Z]
```

In Perl:

```
while (<DATA>) {
  print if  /^(?!.*<[a-zA-Z])/;
}

__DATA__
<Wrong example
Wrong <Example
Good Example
< Good Example
Good < Example
Good< Example
Good Example<
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Good Example
< Good Example
Good < Example
Good< Example
Good Example<
```

Comment: That's perfect, I will take a better look at this ability of the regular expressions, thank you

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be simpler to match for the bad input and blacklist on it instead of matching on good input and whitelisting it.

Reject any input that matches the following regular expression:

```
<[a-zA-Z]
```

If you REALLY need a whitelisting solution (because you don't control the actual validation logic, only the regex), you could do this:

```
^(?:[^<]|<[^a-zA-Z]|<$)*$
```

(You can change the last Kleene star to a plus if you also want to make sure the input is nonempty.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[a-zA-Z]*(<[^a-zA-Z])?[a-zA-Z]*`.

Comment: Thanks, but actually my regex has to be exactly what I said, because I pass it to a program not written by me

Comment: Do you mean the regex must return no matches if there is a < followed by a letter?

Comment: It will be used to validate an input, and I want to accept the input for everything except for a < followed directly by a letter

Comment: @GianT971 - Your regular expression will NOT match what you want it to match, the only way to do that, is to attempt to match it against the correct regular expression

Comment: @Ramhound What about the "If Conditional" of regular expressions? I saw that on the web but I just don't understand it for the moment. For example: http://omegacoder.com/?p=56

Comment: This might be too restrictive, depending on if the OP wants to allow nonalpha in the rest of the expression. Also, it only checks for the valid case (`<` followed by nonalpha) at most once, which might be too restrictive if that pattern appears twice but is not `<` followed by alpha.

Comment: Sorry but this still doesn't work. Borodin gave a correct answer, thanks anyway for your help

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Perhaps not the most ideal pattern, but it matches your "good" examples and does not match your "wrong" examples:

```
^((^|(<[^a-zA-Z]|[^<a-zA-Z])+)[a-zA-Z]+)+(<[^a-zA-Z]*|[^<a-zA-Z]*)$
```

<s>I think you want to use parenthesis followed by a ? to indicate zero or one occurrences of that pattern:</s>

```
(<[^a-zA-Z])?
```

I'm assuming that you are building a larger regex pattern, and is just a part of it.

Comment: I am not building a large regex, it is the only condition I want to check

Comment: This won't work because it will trigger a large number of false positives and false negatives. It will check for zero or one valid cases (`<` followed by nonalpha), so if there are two valid cases this will result in a false negative, and if there is one valid case but also one invalid case (`<` followed by alpha) this will result in a false positive.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could you take a look at my alternative regex and let me know if I happened to miss the mark? I tried to keep it "simple" but I can totally imagine having screwed it up on my end.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure - I was curious myself and gave it a try.  [According to my code](http://dotnetpad.net/ViewPaste/xffuQEhWSUegpUrRtB6UsQ), it only misses the "Good Example<" case.  Still, there is surely a simpler regex than my monstrosity.

Comment: Ooh, good point, I did miss the mark there. I'll edit my post.